# Firefox cross domain fonts

Tags: firefox, fonts, cross-domain

I am trying to write a template for my Blogger blog http://www.mostafa.info, I need to use a custom webfont.Everything goes well in **IE** and **Chrome**, but in **Firefox** that webfont won't render.

If you have a look at my blog with both firefox and chrome, you can see that font are different.

I searched a lot for the problem and I found out that the problem with Firefox is about cross-domain fonts. Those fonts must be hosted on my own Blogger blog (which is impossible!). And let me mention that I tested Google webfonts in Blogger and all went well!

But the question is how can this problem be solved? 
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good way; I embed my webfonts into CSS using base64 like this:

```
@font-face{
 font-family: "myFontName";
 src: url(data:font/woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGZ0ABEAA...AAA)
}
```

In this way It works in all browsers ;) and more important **It is not necessary to have access to filesystem of server** so I can host my CSS/Fonts on google sites

Answer (score 0):

> But the question is how can this problem be solved?

By having the server the fonts are hosted on send the right CORS headers to allow your blogger blog to access them.